# Unable to launch the configured development web server error (VS 2010)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I didn't use my VS10 for a while, and now I've tried to launch some old website of mine that remained untouched so far, but I can't get it running because I get the "Unable to connect to the configured development web server" error. Tried to launch a new empty website but no luck there either, the same issue persists.

I can't change the port number on the left bottom side because it is grayed out for some reason.

Screenshot: [image: screenshot]

Things I've tried:

Launching a new empty website project
Starting as VS as administrator
Restarting PC
deleting folder C:\Users\USER\Documents\IISExpress and opening VS without it (restored it when I could tell it didn't change anything)

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this two suggestions.

**First** option

In the Solution explorer

1. Right-click on the web project in visual studio and select properties.
2. In the menu shown, Select Web from the left bar
3. Under “Use local IIS server” change the port number
4. Run the application

**Second** option

1. Got to the applications root directory.
2. Enable Show hidden files from the View option of the window explorer
3. Delete the .vs directory.
4. Run the project.

Comment: Thanks! But I need some more help

I didn't understand what should I right click on? The solution file from within VS when I open the project? The properties options on the left are not what you mentioned, there's only the Common Properties and the Configuration Properties.

In the second option I didn't find that folder, is that in the Projects folder or in the Websites one? Either way I couldn't find it.

As a side note I'd clarify that I use Win7 and VS10

Comment: Sorry, @Bosco , I Just don't understand what to right-click on, can you tell me where should I, according to the image I posted?

Comment: In the right hand side, the solution explorer, right-click on WebSite10

Comment: The first one ie. the one on the left